# How to xi:include from different jar?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, xinclude

I have a log4j configuration as follows:

```
src/main/resources/log4j2-commons.xml
src/main/resources/log4j2-test.xml

#log4j2-test.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <xi:include href="log4j2-commons.xml" />
</configuration>
```

This setups works fine to include the same commons log configuration in multiple xml configurations.

Now I'd like to move the commons.xml out in a separate jar file, and reference it from there.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: See (and vote for) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-804 - it probably can't be done until this is fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Try this~
href="jar:file:/ {the path you put the jar} / {the name of jar} ! / {the name of the xml}"